# text-overflow: ellipsis show weird characters on IE11

Tags: html, css, kendo-grid

I got issue about text-overflow: ellipsis on 'th' of table.
OS: window7(also 10)
Browser: IE11

There is no this issue on Chrome and Safari (Window and MAC OS).
Long values on cells are converted show values with characters like '...'.
However characters are weird.(browser encoder is set UTF-8)
please check screenshot.

[image]

I checked css(below) is applied on 'th' element.

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

I think this issue can be occured other elements.
How can fix this problem...?

Comment: Normally this is an encoding issue. The browser encoding is set to utf-8 but did you actually save the file itself as utf-8? Try putting: <meta charset="UTF-8"> as first tag in your head of your html see if that helps.

Comment: I already inserted that code(below) on my HTML....hmm
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Can you post the html/css?

Comment: Are you sure the font you are using supports that character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check font family you use(try another one).

Ellipsis actually is not 3 ordinary dots but special single character. For some reason IE cannot find or render this symbol.
Have no idea why this happens to IE only.